# Shipping logs from network share using Filebeat on Windows

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat, elastic-beats

**The problem statement**: I have an application running on Windows. I want to ship logs files from this application to ELK fronted by Kafka.

**The challenge**: This application writes a lot of process metadata to disk under a directory location. This information is important for the application's recovery and hence is stored on a network storage to support DR. The application also writes logs to the same directory location and we do not have the ability to separate the logs from the other process metadata. As a result logs are written to network share.

I want to ship the logs to Elastic. We typically use beats to do this. However, Filebeat does not recommending shipping logs from network storage on Windows. Ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.11/filebeat-network-volumes.html. I have also read various git issues and SO posts where people have complained about Filbeat stopping harvesting on rollover.

Since this is a network share, I was also not able to create a symlink or a Junction link to trick my application to write the logs to the hard disk.

Has anyone solved this issue?

P.S.: I also read somewhere that logstash has better handling of files on network share. However, I do not need logstash and would like to avoid it if possile. Also, logstash official documentation mentions that reading files from NFS is only occasionally tested. It is not thoroughly tested.